# Programmatic JSON Conditionals & Comparisons across Object Properties

Tags: javascript, json

The pseudo-code for the conditionals I'm trying to create:

```js
this.tagSet.forEach((obj) => {

    var tagData = {
        name: obj.tag.name,
        "if": { obj.tag.units: "bool" },
        "then": { "yValueFormatString": "#,##0" },
        "else": {
            "then": { "yValueFormatString": "#,##0.0 " + obj.tag.units }
        },
    };

    tagDataCollection.push(tagData);
});
```

If `obj.tag.units == "bool"` then `yValueFormatString` property should be a certain value. `Else`, another value.

I couldn't find much info in the [standard](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html).

Comment: I would assign the values that should be compared to variables, then do the logic and afterwards push them to the object.

Comment: @e-r-a Yes, certainly possible. However I'm curious to achieve this with this functionality.

Comment: All right then. In this case i cannot help i am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 this.tagSet.forEach((obj) => {
      var temp = obj.tag.units === "bool" ? "#,##0" :"#,##0.0 " + obj.tag.units 
        var tagData = {
            name: obj.tag.name,
            yValueFormatString: temp
        };

        tagDataCollection.push(tagData);
    });
```

Or, even this would do just as well:

```
        var yValueFormatString = obj.tag.units === "bool" ? "#,##0" :"#,##0.0 " + 
           obj.tag.units 
            var tagData = {
                name: obj.tag.name,
                yValueFormatString
            };
```

```js
var a = "foo";

var temp = a=== "foo" ? "something" : "something else"
var obj = {b: "bar", temp};

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I'm curious on how to achieve this using the JSON conditionals. I couldn't find much info.

Comment: The value in `key-value` pairs can be a function, value, variable or a string. You just have to make use of that.

Comment: This looks like a much cleaner solution